# From a string array to a diagram of blocks

Tags: java, user-interface, jgraph

I have made a program which takes the results of some SPARQL queries through Jena and saves them in a 2-dimensional string (i.e., 2-dimensional array of Strings).  I want to take the values of the first column only and design a diagram of blocks where every block contains every value of the first column and links them successively with each other.

From what I have read, [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) seems to be pretty helpful for this, but I downloaded it and tried to do it but I failed.

How could I do this with JGraph, or are there other ways?

[image: something like this]

Comment: Is element 1 always connected to element 2 and so on, or is the order of the String results dependent on the values of the Strings?

Comment: elemnt 1 always connected to the element 2. @GilbertLeBlanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method I put together that will draw a rectangle, fill it with a color, and put a String at the center of the rectangle.

```
/**
 * <p>This method will draw a rectangle and place the text in the center
 * of the rectangle.</p>
 * @param g - Graphics instance from a JPanel paintComponent method
 * @param r - Rectangle (origin and dimension) of the rectangle.
 * @param c - Fill color of the rectangle.
 * @param s - String to place at the center of the rectangle.
 */
public void drawBox(Graphics g, Rectangle r, Color c, String s) {
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
    TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(s, g.getFont(), frc);
    Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();

    int width = (int) Math.round(bounds.getWidth());
    int height = (int) Math.round(bounds.getHeight());
    int x = r.x + (r.width - width) / 2;
    int y = r.y + height + (r.height - height) / 2;

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    layout.draw(g2d, (float) x, (float) y);
}
```

You'll have to figure out where you want the rectangles and how to connect them with skinny rectangles.